# Music and Text in the Same File C#

Tags: c#, file, file-io

If I wanted to have one file, with both an Mp3 track and a text component, how could I accomplish this in C#?

Specific: I am creating a Guitar Hero Clone, and want one file with both the actual sound (an MP3) and the note chart (which I read as text). How would I go about reading and writing these two things into the same file?

Thanks,

Ty Rozak

Comment: Either use ID3 tags or create your own file format.

Comment: Have you thought about using a compressed file (e.g. ZIP, RAR) to package multiple files together? You don't need to use any actual compression, but you can utilize that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define your own file format? first 4 bytes defined how much text is following.... read the text.  Then the rest of the file is MP3.

Answer (score 0):

You could embed them as resources in your assembly by setting the build action to Embedded Resource.

```
// Read the file in from an embedded resource
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string assemblyNamespace = assembly.GetName().Name;
Stream mp3Stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(assemblyNamespace + ".resources.somefile.mp3");

// Then play the sound, or display the text file
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows, you could store information in separate NTFS streams in the same file.
In the command window, try this experiment:

```
NOTEPAD C:\temp\MyFile.mp3
NOTEPAD C:\temp\MyFile.mp3:notes.txt
```

Here is some Microsoft API documentation on how to do this programaticaly:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105763

On Linux, this is available in ReiserFS, but am not sure about ext3.
On this page, they are dicussing storing extra info for binary MP3 data:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/ntfs-vs-ext-file-systems-78636/

Good luck,
Jiri

Comment: Be aware that named streams are not supported in Windows 8: [Building the next generation file system for Windows: ReFS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/01/16/building-the-next-generation-file-system-for-windows-refs.aspx)